# kube-dns and long response time for stubDomains

Tags: dns, kubernetes, stub

I experimented a long response time when my container tried to acces an "external" internal service, like Active Directory... Looking inside, I found in the /etc/resolv.conf the kube-dns IP on the top... In the first attempt, Docker try to resolve my stub domain with kube-dns and take 50 seconds in go to the fallback dns... So, the webpage hang every time (MySQL and AD requests).

I had created too a configmap, but did not work. So my last solution was set the **"hostNetwork: true"** in the pod... And everything goes great... My answer is...

1)What I lost sacrificing the kube-dns in my pod?
2)There is some way to use DNS and dont wait 50 seconds to pass to the second DNS server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I'm wasn't have the kube-dns container correctly installed and configured... The IP in /etc/resolv.conf wasn't not exist...